# Sending Emil from server SMTP is blocked by several email clients but from Gmail it works why?

Tags: .net, email, webserver

When we send emails from our server it does not reach several email clients (not even the spam folders)

But when trying to send the same email from Gmail API it works great.

(we are sending only several hundreds emails a day, each one to a separate user,

the problem reproduced when sending html or plain text, and the server IP is not blacklisted)

What can be the cause of the email getting blocked?

What is the best way to ensure an email will not get blocked?

(the simple send email code is added below)

Thanks

Rafael

```
 //(1) Create the MailMessage instance
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(EmailFromAddress, ToEmail);

    //(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
    mm.From = new MailAddress(EmailFromAddress, EmailFromName);
    mm.Subject = Subject;

    mm.Body = GetHtmlMessage(Body);

    mm.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mm.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    //(3) Create the SmtpClient object - Config in the Web.Config
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;

    smtp.Send(mm);
```

Comment: In your post, you have mentioned ‘several clients’ are these client internal or external and are they on the same domain (served by the same POP/IMAP server).  Did you try sending email directly from outlook, configured with your smtp server?

Comment: I meant external email provider like hotmail yahoo gmail...

Comment: Ok, pls try sending email to some of those clients using outlook configured with your SMTP server and verify whether the mail is delivered

Comment: I used Telnet to send smtp email from the server, to gmail it's OK, but to those clients the mail never shows.

Comment: This can only mean your SMTP server is black listed and nothing to do with your C# code. Your clients may try white listing you’re the server. Please make sure your domain can be reverse looked up, your network administrator should be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the port on the `SmtpClient` class. It is 25, the default. Try that and see.